# Jquery removeData not working for modal that is called with href inorder to pass $_GET values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a website that populates a table dynamically from the database, and each row on the table has a button that calls launches a modal to view more details of that particular row (details are also dynamically generated from the database) and makes database updates. So in order to pass the needed values to my modal.

I declared the modal on the same page

```
<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false"  id="add_branchProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add_branchProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

then i called the rest of my modal with an href to pass database id's

```
echo "<td width='20px'>
       <a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id=\"branch\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target='#add_branchProductModal' 
href='modals/add_branchProductModal.php?id3={$_SESSION['store_key']}&id={$products['product_key']}&id2={$category['category_key']}' role='button'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span>
 </a>
</td>";
```

My problem is I also make form updates using jquery to avoid page reloads, but because I'm calling the rest of the modal with an href I have to link my jquery libs to that particular page else it wouldn't respond, of which I do not really understand why. But when i do this it works fine. The only problem is, on the page where the modal is called from, my jquery script which helps my remove data from my modal when closed stops working and only this particular script. Here is the script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add_branchProductModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
              $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i remove the jquery libs from my href modal page the script above works just fine, but I wouldn't be able to make an update using jquery and avoid a page reload

here is the code for calling the modal with href (the entire page)

```
<?php
  include '../connection/connect.php';
  $store_key = $_GET['id3'];
  $category_key = $_GET['id2'];
  $date = date("M, l Y", strtotime('Today'));

<div class="modal-header">                                                                               
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="products_summaryLabel">Date: (<?php echo $date;?>)</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">                                                    
  <section id="content">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="container clearfix">
      <form id="register_formProduct1">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="category">
        <?php 
          $query = "SELECT * FROM product_category WHERE store_key = '{$store_key}' AND category_key = '{$category_key}' LIMIT 1";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
            echo "<option value='{$result['category_key']}'>".  ucfirst($result['category_name'])."</option>";
          }
        ?>
               </select><button type="button">Submit</button>
             </td>
           </tr> 
         </table>
        </form>
    </div>
   </section><!-- #content end -->
   <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table").keyup(function(){
    var pieces_entered = +$("#pieces_entered").val();
    var available_pieces = +$("#available_pieces").val();
    var sum = (pieces_entered + available_pieces);
    var pieces = $("#pieces").val(sum);
   });

   $("#submit_product1").click(function() {  
    var category_key = $("#category_key").val();
    var branch_code = $("#branch_code").val();
    var product_name = $("#product_name").val();
    var product_key = $("#product_key").val();
    var pieces = $("#pieces").val();
    var category_key = $("#category_key").val();
    var reorder = $("#reorder").val();
    var exp_date = $("#exp_date").val();
    var note = $("#note").val();
    if (exp_date == '' || reorder == '' || category_key == '' || pieces == '' || branch_code == '' || product_key == '' || product_name == '') {
    window.alert("Insertion Failed, Some Fields are Blank....!!");
    } else {                                                     
if(pieces < reorder){ 
 window.alert("Re-order Level cannot be greater than pieces available!!");    
}else{
 // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    $.post("scripts/product_update.php", {
    category_key1: category_key,
    branch_code1: branch_code,
    product_key1: product_key,
    product_name1: product_name,
    pieces1: pieces,
    //measurement1: measurement,
    //price1: price,
    reorder1: reorder,
    exp_date1: exp_date,
    note1: note
    }, function(data) {
        window.alert("Product successfully added!!!");
        $('#register_formProduct1')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
    });
    }
    });
    });
</script>
```

How can I make both scripts work for me simultaneously?

Comment: so hidden.bs.modal is calling or not

Comment: it's doesn't call when i link my jquery libs to my href modal page, but it works when i remove it, only that i need my jquery libs on my href modal page to submit a form with jquery.

Comment: Where is `#invoiceModal` ? The only modal you mentioned in your question is having id `add_branchProductModal`

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong code, but i've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal in my page:

```
<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false"  id="add_branchProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add_branchProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My `<a>` tag that i used to call the modal body and send variables to it

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='branch' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_branchProductModal' 
   href='modals/add_branchProductModal.php?id3={$_SESSION['store_key']}&id={$products['product_key']}&id2={$category['category_key']}' role='button'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span>
 </a>"
```

I called the function to submit my form within my modal when it opens

```
$('#add_branchProductModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Function that submits my form within the modal body
  $("#submit_product1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      var form = e.target;
      var data = new FormData(form);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["form_name"])) {
      alert("Insertion Failed, Some Fields are Blank....!!");
    } else {                                                     
     if(data.get('pieces') < data.get('reorder')){ 
      alert("Re-order Level cannot be greater than pieces available!!");    
     }else{
       $.post("scripts/product_update.php",{
        data:data
       }, function(data) {
           alert("Product successfully added!!!");
           $('#register_formProduct1')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
      });
     }
   }
  });
});
```

clear modal on close

```
$('#add_branchProductModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```